# Not getting some of the comment and badge notifications

Tags: support, bug, notifications

**Comments Notifications**: I recently commented on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1085041/816190). Earlier whenever I used to comment on a post and get a reply from OP just after my comment *even without mentioning my name*, I used to get notifications, but since some days I am not getting more than 2 comment notifications. I use Stack Exchange app on my Android which sends me all notifications and website on Firefox, neither of them received a notification regarding the same.

**Badge Notifications**: I recently edited a tag due to which I earned **Tag Editor** badge a few hours ago. Earlier I used to get the notifications regarding badges but now no notification is there.

I believe that above are due to recent changes in the website and consider it as a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the system is working in its intended and slightly confusing way.

#### You only get comment notifications when the system thinks the message is for you

You made [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085041/how-to-completely-remove-elementary-os-ubuntu-18-04) that the OP replied to without @'ing you. If you had been the only user apart from the author who commented on that post, [you would have been notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications/125212#125212) (this explains why you've received notifications without being @'d in the past), but since other people had also commented, when the OP replied, the system didn't know which of the commenters should be notified, so didn't notify any of them.

#### You only get badge notifications when the system thinks you'll actually care

TIL, not all bronze badges cause notifications for users who are considered "veterans" (those who have earned 200 reputation on any site and therefore get an association bonus on every site they join).

Only silver and gold badges, and [the bronze badges listed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138113/which-badges-do-not-cause-a-notification-for-experienced-users) trigger badge notifications, presumably to avoid notification-fatigue for lots of unexciting badges.